# C# search for specific string with specific length

Tags: c#, regex, search

I have a giant xml and i am supposed to search for specific strings in it.

Strings must be 13 letters long and has to be all numeric.

I believe using regex is suitable for such application but my knowledge of regex is limited so that any kind of example would be useful.

Also what other approaches can be used for such string search applications.

```
  <field name="TKT">
    <item>
      <index>1</index> 
        <text>Y24AUGXLOWS 2352159617737</text> 
    </item>
  </field>
  <field name="AP FAX">
    <item>
      <index>1</index> 
        <text>1 S1 SSRTKNETKHK1 2352159617737C1</text> 
    </item>
  </field>
```

This is example of part of the xml im talking about. For instance I would like to extract number "2352159617737".

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide an example of the xml? is it specific words you are looking for, or elements which have 13 characters?

Comment: A quick google search on "c# regex guide" lead to [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial) which has an example of finding numeric strings.

Comment: Is it too-big-to-fit-in-memory-giant or ...?

Comment: Lol. What an explosion of answers there. I dont mind over-spamming my solution... but cant get the point.

Comment: @cagdasumay: Once you find out the solution you accepted does not fetch you any results if the number is at the beginning of the string, please come back and choose the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go the regex-way you could use this expression:

```
[^\d](\d{13})[^\d]
```

This one only grabs 13-character long numbers.

[Regex101 Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/wE4hS5/7)

*Updated with your xml-code*
*Shortened the expression*

Comment: Will it? And if this number is not inside `<text>` tag?

Comment: I cant see any condition in the question where he only wants to grab between text-tags. @cagdasumay if it solved it, consider marking the answer then. Otherwise if you truly need a text-tag-filter, tell me.

Comment: However, this is a wrong answer because it will never match a number at the beginning of the string. Negated character classes are not the same as negative look-arounds. Please see the regex in my answer for a correct solution.

Comment: @w.b Right. "Strings must be 13 letters long" is the spelling of his condition. Therefore why shouldnt the expression only catch string that are exactly 13 characters long? Cant get your point.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for the information! Seriously havnt known this point.

Comment: @stribizhev: The input is xml so it is impossible for the string to be at the beginning or end of the file. It must have some kind of enclosing tag (as far as I know) which means there will always be content before and after any valid string. I will agree that this is an important point to be made though on the differences between what was done and negative lookarounds. I am mainly just disagreeing with the assertion that this answer is wrong - for this specific circumstance it will work fine.

Comment: @Chris: I agree with you: it is a special case where incorrect approach has a merit :) As if an exception that proves the rule. Sure, this answer is not wrong.

Comment: Deep-going definition-discussion. For myself Im still thinking about why the hell regex behaves like `Nothing != NoDigit`. Therefore `Only a char can be a no-digit`. Isnt that confusing? From the view where you chould just say `(EveryOtherChar || NoCharAtAll) == NoDigit`? Unexpected behaviour of regex to me. The `most likely logic` isnt taken in here.

Answer (score 2):

If you only expect to get the numbers from `<text>` tags and other tag may also contain similar numbers, but you want to avoid matching them, use regex with XML parser. Here is an XElement-based solution:

```
var xml = "<field name=\"TKT\"> - <item> <index>1</index> <text>Y24AUGXLOWS 2352159617737</text> </item> </field> - <field name=\"AP FAX\"> - <item> <index>1</index> <text>1 S1 SSRTKNETKHK1 2352159617737C1</text> </item> </field>";
var xe = XElement.Parse("<root>" + xml + "</root>");
var res = xe.Descendants("text").Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
var numbers = new List<string>();
foreach (var tag in res)
{ 
    numbers.AddRange(Regex.Matches(tag, @"(?<!\d)\d{12}(?!\d)").Cast<Match>().Select(n => n.Value).ToList());
}
```

[image]

With any regex that deals with "number" extraction, you should understand its boundaries and use it according to your needs:

- `\d{13}` will fetch you 13-digit sequences even if they are part of a longer numeric sequence (`1234567890123456` will give you `1234567890123`)
- `(?<!\d)\d{13}(?!\d)` will get you all 13-digit sequences *if* not followed or preceded with a digit (thus, `A1234567890123B` is a valid match)
- `\b\d{13}\b` will only match if enclosed with non-word characters (only `,1234567890123;`-like strings are valid matches.

Comment: BTW, even if you do not consider parsing the XML, my regex can be used with pure text input as `var numbers = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!\d)\d{12}(?!\d)").Cast<Match>().Select(n => n.Value).ToList());`.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this expression:

```
\b(\d{13})\b
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xW8pZ0/4)

Note that it will capture all 13 digit text from your xml, if you specifically want to target `<text>` node it is also possible through xpath query. An example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576505/xpath-to-first-occurrence-of-element-with-text-length-200-characters):

```
root.SelectNodes("html/body/.//*[(name() !='script') and (name()!='style')]/text()[string-length() > 200]")
```

Answer (score 1):

`@"\d{13}?"` will give you 13-digit numbers:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

var numbers = doc.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>()
                      .Where(t => Regex.IsMatch(t, @"\d{13}?"))
                      .Select(t => Regex.Match(t, @"\d{13}?").Value)
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[^\d](\d{13})[^\d]` regular expression to validate your string. If you want to change the string length in the regular expression then just put what ever you want in the place of `13`

Comment: This seems to be the same as C4ud3x's answer from an hour earlier and doesn't seem to add anything...

Answer (score 0):

C4ud3x answer actually is right, but I think it can be done also like this: `([0-9]{13})`

Comment: It cant. He only wants string that are 13 characters long. This way you would also grab 13 characters out of string with for example 20 characters which isnt his goal.

Comment: I know, but I didn't see where he wrote that it's wrong